# How can I get line numbers relative to the cursor position in the editor gutter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I started using the Vim extension for VS Code. I want to make my line numbers display like they do for me in Neovim, but I couldn't find any solution for it.

[my editor gutter right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKK4I.png)

[I want this style of line numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmxGB.png)

Comment: search settings for `line number`

Comment: Note that the answer to this question can also be found in [Relative line numbers in Visual Studio](/q/4967217/11107541), but I believe that's the wrong place for that answer to go, since that question is about Visual Studio and not VS Code, so I have chosen for my self not to vote this question as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `editor.lineNumbers` setting and set it to `"relative"`.

Ex. in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.lineNumbers": "relative"
```

The setting reads as follows in the default settings:

> ```json
> // Controls the display of line numbers.
> //  - off: Line numbers are not rendered.
> //  - on: Line numbers are rendered as absolute number.
> //  - relative: Line numbers are rendered as distance in lines to cursor position.
> //  - interval: Line numbers are rendered every 10 lines.
> "editor.lineNumbers": "on",>
> ```